# Postfix delivers messages locally despite configuration for discovering external agent

Tags: dns, email, postfix, sendmail, smtp

A small node operates several web applications attached to a domain.

The same domain is used for mailboxes, hosted off site by a commercial service.

On the name server operated by the registrar, *A*, *AAAA*, and *CNAME* records are used to resolve the web server, whereas *MX* records are used to resolve the commercial mail service.

Applications on the web server must deliver mail addressed within the same domain.

Postfix runs on the server, and correctly transfers messages for addresses of other domains based on resolving their *MX* records. However, messages detected as addressed for a local domain are not transferred to external delivery agents, but rather retained for local delivery, despite that the *MX* records for the domain give an alternative domain corresponding to the commercial service.

The [documentation for Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) suggests that the desired behavior may be realized by setting a value for the configuration parameter `mydestination` that excludes as an item in the value list `$mydomain`.

An [answer posted elsewhere on the StackExchange network](https://serverfault.com/a/854108/589665) gives a similar suggestion, of setting the configuration as follows:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

In fact, such is the actual value currently set, being the default provided by the software stack operating on the host.

Log output is shown below for a message processed by Postfix. The machine host name is substituted with `myhostname.myhostplace.tld`, and the domain name configured in the mail subsystem is substituted with `example.tld`, with the mail account used in the message represented as `testuser`.

Given that the assigned local domain is not included in the criteria for identifying addresses for local delivery of messages, why are messages addressed within the local domain nonetheless still being locally delivered?

---

```
postfix/smtpd[11339]: warning: No server certs available. TLS won't be enabled
postfix/smtpd[11339]: connect from localhost[::1]
postfix/smtpd[11339]: F41793F5F: client=localhost[::1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=testuser@example.tld
postfix/cleanup[11344]: F41793F5F: message-id=<20230816195532.F41793F5F@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/qmgr[10533]: F41793F5F: from=<testuser@example.tld>, size=795, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[11339]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=5
postfix/lmtp[11346]: F41793F5F: to=<testuser@example.tld>, relay=myhostname.myhostplace.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.32, delays=0.28/0.01/0.02/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <testuser@example.tld> IKcXErUp3WRTLAAAcQihng Saved)
postfix/qmgr[10533]: F41793F5F: removed
```

```
postfix/pickup[17489]: 72E744073: uid=0 from=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/cleanup[19587]: 72E744073: message-id=<20230816215541.72E744073@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/qmgr[10533]: 72E744073: from=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>, size=3595, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtp[19589]: 72E744073: to=<root@localhost>, relay=none, delay=1.3, delays=1.3/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)
postfix/cleanup[19587]: AAD6A4165: message-id=<20230816215542.AAD6A4165@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/bounce[19590]: 72E744073: sender non-delivery notification: AAD6A4165
postfix/qmgr[10533]: AAD6A4165: from=<>, size=5766, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[10533]: 72E744073: removed
postfix/smtp[19589]: AAD6A4165: to=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for myhostname.myhostplace.tld loops back to myself)
postfix/qmgr[10533]: AAD6A4165: removed
postfix/pickup[17489]: 5BF2E4073: uid=0 from=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/cleanup[19775]: 5BF2E4073: message-id=<20230816215813.5BF2E4073@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/qmgr[10533]: 5BF2E4073: from=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>, size=3696, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtp[19777]: 5BF2E4073: to=<root@localhost>, relay=none, delay=0.77, delays=0.76/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)
postfix/cleanup[19775]: A02D04165: message-id=<20230816215813.A02D04165@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>
postfix/bounce[19778]: 5BF2E4073: sender non-delivery notification: A02D04165
postfix/qmgr[10533]: A02D04165: from=<>, size=5867, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[10533]: 5BF2E4073: removed
postfix/smtp[19777]: A02D04165: to=<root@myhostname.myhostplace.tld>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for myhostname.myhostplace.tld loops back to myself)
```

Comment: Maybe because Postfix checks "first" if the domain is local (in mydestination parameter), and if this domain is not local, it checks the mx of the domain to relay the mail to the right mx server. Normally, if the domain belong external mx server, you must'nt  declare the domain locally (remove it from mydestination), then restart Postfix server.

Comment: @totoaussi: As I would understand, since the domain is omitted from the value of `mydestination`, the check for its being local should fail.

Comment: Yes, remove it from mydestination, because mydestination is for local domains. Otherwise, Postfix always delivers mail to local mail server if the recipient domain is a local domain.

Comment: @totoaussi: Where is the domain given as included in `mydestination`?

Comment: postconf -nx myhostname command returns your local domain ? I forgot to say that virtual domains declared in your postfix server are also local domains. Is your local domain is declared as virtual domain in your postfix server ?

Comment: @totoaussi The command you gave prints a domain name used for the network infrastructure, but not one relevant to any email addresses. I suppose the answer is that no, the command does not print the local domain.

Comment: So maybe the problem is that your domain is declared as virtual domain in your postfix server. When you send mail with domain, what does the logs says ?

Comment: @totoaussi: I posted log output in the question. Please see the transcript, as well as the note in the paragraph before the last.